# Anylogic: how to calculate the cumulative sum?

Tags: events, anylogic, cumulative-sum, systemdynamics

I would like to know how to calculate the cumulative sum in Anylogic. Specifically, I have a cyclic event that changes the value of a parameter every week. From this parameter I would like to calculate the cumulative sum of the values it received, how can I do that ?

The event is a Timeout with mode Cyclic. The action is:

"name_parameter"=round(max(normal(10,200),0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parameter with an initial value of 0. Call it sum. In the event action field use:

```
name_parameter = round(max(normal(10,200),0));
sum += name_parameter;
```

Comment: the correct way of doing it is sum += name_parameter, not =+ so i'm surprised it worked

Comment: Thank you for noticing the mistake. I fixed it. He probably knows the syntax and figured it out.

Comment: yes I knew the syntax but forgot to report it (forgive me).